# Pandas drop column in place and return it

Tags: pandas, dataframe

This seems clunky:

```py
col = df['col']
df.drop(columns=['col'], inplace=True)
```

Is there a way to drop a columns and return it on the same line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you need `df.pop()`

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.randint(0, 10, (4,3)), columns=['a','b','c'])
a = df.pop("a")
```